# Mysqli database name change on button click

Tags: javascript, php

I have these dropdown options that should redirect me to another page to view different academic records on yearly basis. On the new page, I want to display different data from another database (for that year). Basically, I want to change my database name whenever any of those buttons are click but I want to achieve that with only one config file.

Here is my html code

```
<li class="parent"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-item-2">
        <em class="fa fa-calendar">&nbsp;</em> Academic Year <span data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-item-2" class="icon pull-right"><span class="elegant" data-icon="&#x3b;"></span></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="children collapse" id="sub-item-2">
        <li class="year1">
            <?php
            $year1 = "2020/2021";
            $year2 = "2021/2022";

            if ($_SESSION['branch'] == "Ayela") {
                echo "<a class='' href='/tm/2020-2021/ayela'>
                    <span class='elegant' data-icon='&#x35;'>&nbsp;</span> $year1
                </a>";
            }

            if ($_SESSION['branch'] == "Ayela") {
                echo "<a class='' href='/tm/2021-2022/ayela'>
                    <span class='elegant' data-icon='&#x35;'>&nbsp;</span> $year2
                </a>";
            }
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

PHP code
'config.php'

```
if ($year1 == TRUE) {
    $dbServername = "localhost";
    $dbUsername = "root";
    $dbPassword = "";
    $dbName = "mydb_2020";

    /* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
    $link = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

    // Check connection
    if ($link === false) {
        die("ERROR: Could not connect.");
    }
}
if ($year2 == TRUE) {
    $dbServername = "localhost";
    $dbUsername = "root";
    $dbPassword = "";
    $dbName = "mydb_2021";

    /* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
    $link = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

    // Check connection
    if ($link === false) {
        die("ERROR: Could not connect.");
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Interesting question as to why it's necessary to have a new database for every year? Is there really so much data that it was causing performance issues to have them all in one? That should really be the only sensible reason to archive data in this way. The only other thought I've got is that your schema isn't designed correctly and therefore doesn't support multiple years properly. If you just had one database, then this problem would go away.

Comment: But anyway aside from that, what's stopping you from achieving what you want? What have you tried? What went wrong? I can see you're including the year (hard-coded, which is going to be a maintenance headache in future) in the URL. Maybe you're struggling to extract that from the URL when PHP receives the request? It can be done, but if you just put it as a GET parameter it would be much easier. Either way, you haven't shown the code which is actually supposed to process these requests.

Comment: in your html code I see no `"dropdown options"`, it is unclear where the `config` file is used and if you are using the statically declared variables `$year1 = "2020/2021";` etc in the config then both will be true

Comment: Hi Joseph, Thanks for posting in stack overflow , its a new question good, so as I understand you need to create database every button click ? but why we need to create new databases every time instead of using existing database ,is there any problem in using existing database.

Comment: I do not want to create a new database when the button is clicked. The database is already available but I want to display information from that database when the user in the "/tm/2021-2022/ayela" directory